# POST array being deleted when page loads

Tags: php, post, http-post

I'm having an issue guys, I `POST` data from a `form` to another page and do the following in relation to the code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Confirm Registration Page
 * 
*/ 
    $course = $_POST['course_title'];
    $location = $_POST['course_location'];
    $date   = $_POST['course_date'];
    $qty    = $_POST['attendlist'];

    $_POST = array(); <------- Need to clear the POST array so handler is not 
                               called first time user is on page.

    if (!empty($_POST)){
    $processOrder = register_course_handler(); <--- Handler
    }  
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Main Container -->
    <div id="main_box">
        <h1><?= $course . " " . $date ?></h1>
        <h2><?= $location ?></h2>
        <? the_content() ?>
        <!-- Display a form with x amount of fields Name, Email, Number -->
        <form action="#" method="POST">
        <table>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <? for($i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++):?>
            <tr><td>Guest <?= $i + 1?></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_id" value="<?= the_ID() ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_title" value="<?= the_title() ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_date" value="<?= date("d-m-Y", strtotime(get_sub_field('date'))) ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_location" value="<? the_sub_field('venue') ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_applicant" value="<?= $user_ID ?>"/>
            </tr>
            <? endfor; ?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm Registration"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <!-- Shopping Cart Panel (Top Right) -->
<?php include 'order_panel.php'?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I would like the `form` to resubmit to the current page. I then have a handler in another file which will handle the submission. Currently the problem is that the handler never gets called because the `POST` array is cleared every time the page loads. The reason I tried clearing it was because if I did not then the handler would be called the first time the user is brought to the page.

Any advice on how I might fix this issue?

```
array (size=9)
  'name' => string '' (length=0)     <------- These fields are blank....
  'email' => string '' (length=0)
  'phone' => string '' (length=0)
  'course_id' => string '1063' (length=4)
  'course_title' => string 'Energy use in Mushroom Units' (length=28)
  'formSend2' => string '1' (length=1)
  'course_date' => string '23-07-2014' (length=10)
  'course_location' => string 'Teagasc, Thurles' (length=16)
  'course_applicant' => string '1' (length=1)
```

My HTML for the blank fields. I enter in values in browser but blank

```
<td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"/></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formSend" value="1" />
```

Change the check from `if (!empty($_POST)){` to

```
if (isset($_POST['formSend'])){
```

Don't do `$_POST = array();`.

Comment: Your answer is working but having a slight issue with the data that is being posted, can you take a look at my changes to the OP

Comment: Never mind, solved it, thanks for your help. Very good Answer!